# MATLAB error using symfun/subsindex

Tags: algorithm, matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I'm having trouble using `dsolve` with symbolic functions. I'm receiving an error stating:

> "Error using symfun/subsindex (line 121)
>   Indexing values must be positive integers, logicals or symbolic variables.
>
> Error in VK3 (line 9)
>   [F(n), G(n), H(n)] = dsolve(diff(F) == F2, diff(G) == G2,..."

Here's my code as it stands. This may seem stupid to some, but I have relatively little experience with Matlab. If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong, I'd be grateful.

```
syms F(n) G(n) H(n) F2(n) G2(n)

c = 1.004e-6;
m = input('Angular Velocity = ');
z = 0:1:20;
r = input('Radial Distance = ');
n = z*sqrt(m/c);

[F(n), G(n), H(n)] = dsolve(diff(F) == F2, diff(G) == G2,...
                            diff(F2) == F^2 - G^2 + F2*H,...
                            diff(G2) == 2*F + G2*H,...
                            diff(H) == -2*F,...
                            F(0) == 0, H(0) == 0, G(0) == 1, F(20) == 0, G(20) == 0);

U = m*r*F(n);
V = m*r*G(n);
W = sqrt(m/v)*H(n);

subplot(3,1,1)      
plot(U,n), xlabel('U'), ylabel('z'),...
           title('Radial Velocity Component')

subplot(3,1,2)      
plot(V,n), xlabel('V'), ylabel('z'),...
           title('Azimuthal Velocity Component')

subplot(3,1,3)         
plot(W,n), xlabel('W'), ylabel('z'),...
           title('Axial Velocity Component')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the issue is with the line calling [`dsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html). As the documentation [indicates](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html#bs220sw-5), this function either returns either

> - Symbolic array that contains solutions of an equation. The size of a symbolic array corresponds to the number of the solutions.
> - Structure array that contains solutions of a system of equations. The number of fields in the structure array corresponds to the number of independent variables in a system.
> - Variables to which the solver assigns the solutions of a system of equations. The number of output variables or symbolic arrays must equal the number of independent variables in a system. The toolbox sorts independent variables alphabetically, and then assigns the solutions for these variables to output variables or symbolic arrays.

In other words, it does not return symbolic functions ([`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html)). Thus, Matlab sees `F(n)` as array indexing rather than a symbolic function. I recommend using the structure array form:

```
S = dsolve(diff(F) == F2,
           diff(G) == G2,...
           diff(F2) == F^2 - G^2 + F2*H,...
           diff(G2) == 2*F + G2*H,...
           diff(H) == -2*F,...
           F(0) == 0, H(0) == 0, G(0) == 1, F(20) == 0, G(20) == 0);
```

However, your system may not have an analytic solution (do you have reason to believe that it does?) because you'll get a warning:

> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.

and the output `S` will be empty. You could try [applying `assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-1.html). (Mathematica 10 doesn't fare any better, for what it's worth.)